# GA for Azure AD B2C (ROPC)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

we are planning to use ROPC in our Production solution but we want to ensure that the service is GA before we move our implementation.

Can any one give an indication when this will go GA?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact time for this. We can only monitor the updates, roadmap, and announcements of Azure products [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?status=all&Page=2).